# How to receive extras from pendingintent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have a service that starts notification:

```
public class Notify extends Service{
@Override
public void onCreate() {

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, 0);

        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Notification noti_builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setSound(uri)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        noti_builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti_builder);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Service starts inside other class here:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
Intent intent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, Notify.class);
intent.putExtra("id", ID);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AddAlarm.this, 0, intent, 0);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notifyDate.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

I want to get extras inside service. Any suggestion how to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Notify class, move your code from the onCreate method to the onStartCommand method which has the following signature

```
onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

then you can access the extras from the intent passed into the method.

Comment: Thank You, it works.

 
Can I have another question? With this code I receive few notofications instead of one. Where did I made mistake? Should I change pendingintent flag to something else?

Comment: How many notifications do you receive?  Are they duplicates?  Or are you trying to "over-write" existing notifications if they are there?  Thanks.

Comment: Usually there are 3 and more (5-6) notifications that I receive after execute this code. All are duplicates. I execute this code only once with button click. What I already noticed is that when I restart app completly (delete it from home button menu and start it again) duplicate notification shows immediately after app started. When I changed it to onStartCommand instead of onCreate when duplication shows app crash. Thanks.